# Simplification of Faulhaber's formula

Tags: number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

The fact that
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^m=\dfrac{1}{m+1}\displaystyle\sum_{s=0}^m \dbinom{m+1}{s}\mathrm B_{s}n^{m-s+1} \tag*{(1)}$$
should imply
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^m=\dfrac{1}{m+1}\displaystyle\sum_{s=0}^m (-1)^s \dbinom{m+1}{s}\mathrm B_{s}n^{m-s+1}. \tag*{(2)}$$
It should be true because $\mathrm B_{2s+1}=0$ for $s\ge 1$, but I don't understand how $\mathrm B_{2s+1}=0$ implies $(2)$.
If I change every $n$ to $n+1$ in $(1)$, then
$$\begin{align*}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^m&=\dfrac{1}{m+1}\displaystyle\sum_{s=0}^m \dbinom{m+1}{s}\mathrm B_{s}\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{m-s+1}\dbinom{m-s+1}{t}n^t\\&=\dfrac{1}{m+1}\displaystyle\sum_{s=0}^m\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{m-s+1}\mathrm B_{s}\dbinom{m+1}{s}\dbinom{m-s+1}{t}n^t\\&=\dfrac{1}{m+1}\displaystyle\sum_{s=0}^m\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{m-s+1}\mathrm B_{s}\dbinom{m+1}{s+t}\dbinom{s+t}{s}n^t\\&=\dfrac{1}{m+1}\displaystyle\sum_{s=0}^m\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{m-s+1}\dfrac{\mathrm B_{s}}{s! \, t! \, (s+t)!}\dbinom{m+1}{s+t}n^t,\end{align*}$$
but I don't know how to proceed. Is there way to get rid of the double sum?

Comment: The point is that $(-1)^s$ is 1 when $s$ is even, so putting it in it doesn't affect the nonzero terms.

Comment: To me, it seems arbitrary to multiply by $(-1)^s$. What is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The summands in (1) with $s$ even are unaffected by multiplication by $(-1)^s=1$.  The terms with $s$ odd and greater than 1 are also unaffected because all such terms are 0, thanks to the factor of $B_s=0$.  Thus, the only term that is affected is the term with $s=1$, and it is easy to check that this change on the right hand side changes the sum in precisely the same way as the change on the left hand side.

Comment: Multiplication by $(-1)^s$ seems arbitrary in that case. Could you please elaborate on "checking" the sides?

Comment: @Tu1 as for checking the sides, the difference between the right hand sides of (1) and (2) is just the difference between the first summands, since all summands are the same.  This difference is $n^m$.  The difference between the left hand sides of (1) and (2) is also $n^m$, since we are just adding an additional term to the sum.  Since we are adding the same thing to both sides of (1) to get (2), the equations (1) and (2) are equivalent.

Comment: @Tu1 as for why we multiply by $(-1)^s$, I’m not sure if this is the full reason, but it does make the expression in the Umbral calculus more compact.  I have also heard something about how some authors used to define the Bernoulli numbers with $B_1$ equal to what we would call $-B_1$ today... this is equivalent to saying that some authors used to define $B_s$ to be what we call $(-1)^sB_s$ today, which might be relevant but I’m not sure.